# Список через input с фиксированной длиной

Tags: python

`n=int(input()) s=ln(list(input()) #длина введенного списка (почему-то стак не пропускает оператор) while s<n:`

что-то написал, но как дальше не понимаю, подскажите как задать фиксированную дину списка, т.е. определить условие конца ввода и принимать неограниченное количество элементов до наступления этого условия

Answer (score 0):

наверное так можно сделать:

```
n = int(input())
data = list(map(int, input().split()))[:n]
```

или если длина списка была меньше заданного числа, то можно так:

```
n = int(input())
data = (list(map(int, input().split())) + [0]*n)[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то можно сделать вот так:

```
array = []
s= int(input()) #Длина списка

for i in range(s): 
    number = int(input()) 
    array.append(number) #Добавление новых элементов списка
```